# Cannot connect to AWS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to this whole EC2 thing, so maybe I set it up wrong or something.

I created an application with a web tier and an application tier.

I set the RDS engine to sqlserver-ex (which I'm guessing is SQL server Express?) and then a Single Availabilty Zone, since this is just me testing some things out.

The error I'm getting in SSMS is this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Time-out van wachtbewerking.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

I'm not even able to ping it, should I be able to? Is there something else I need to configure on AWS?

Comment: You might need to check the security groups assigned to your RDS instance and more specifically ensure that port 1433 is allowed in your ingress rules. Also make sure that the RDS you created has a public IP.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks, aparently it hadn't automatically set outbound rules on the security group, which I think is pretty weird? Anyway, make that into an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Added the comment as answer.

Comment: This blog post help me solve my connection issue:
https://msayem.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/unable-to-connect-to-aws-rds-from-sql-server-management-studio/ As per the responses above, it has to do with "inbound" security setting. You have to enter 1433 into the setting as per the blog post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to check the security groups assigned to your RDS instance and more specifically ensure that port 1433 is allowed in your ingress rules. Also make sure that the RDS you created has a public IP.

Comment: What if the RDS SQL Server instance is in a private subnet in VPC A and VPC B has a private subnet trying to connect to VPC A over Transit Gateway? Do you still require the instance to have public access?